# How can I get scm manager running in a docker container to use an existing directory on the host system for configuration and repos

Tags: scmmanager

When I start scm manager via docker:

`docker run sdorra/scm-manager`

How do I get scm manager to retrieve/store its configuration data and repositories from/to an existing directory on the main filesystem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use docker volumes to achieve this. With a docker volume you can mount a folder from your host into your container. In the case of the scm-manager home directory this could look like this:

```sh
docker run -v /host/path:/var/lib/scm sdorra/scm-manager:1.60
```

The left side of the "-v" parameter specifies the path on the host filesystem and the right side specifies the path in the container.

**Note:** The scm-manager docker container uses a user with the uid 1000, so you have to be sure that the user can read and write this volume: `chown -R 1000:1000 /host/path`.